# SQL Select Dealers that have only sold one product

Tags: sql

I am trying to create SQL statement for the following

What I am trying to accomplished is an output that would only show the IDs that have only sold the A Product. Thus ID 5546 would be excluded because they have sold the B Product. Thanks!

```
+------------+---------+
|            |         |
+------------+---------+
| Dealercode | Product |
| 5546       | A       |
| 5546       | B       |
| 2214       | A       |
| 3654       | A       |
|            |         |
| Output     |         |
| Dealercode | Product |
| 2214       | A       |
| 3654       | A       |
+------------+---------+
```

Comment: what did you try to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is almost a basic aggregation query, but with a twist:

```
select dealercode, max(product) as product
from table t
group by dealercode
having count(distinct product) = 1;
```

If there is only one product, then `max(product)` will be that product.  The `having` clause guarantees only one product for each dealer (assuming `product` is never `NULL`).

If you are learning SQL, you should study up on `group by` and `having`.  These are fundamental parts of the language.

EDIT:

Ah, "only sold the A Product" (I think I read "only sold a product").  Then use:

```
select dealercode, max(product) as product
from table t
group by dealercode
having min(product) = max(product) and min(product) = 'A';
```

Comment: Don't forget to filter that the product is 'A'

Comment: as @RadioActiveEd pointed out, this does not appear to give the result you want if you add a row (5546, 'B'), as that will appear in the output but the question indicated you only wanted rows associated with product A (rather than just any one product)